# Replacing special characters that are within quotes inside files

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I didn't find an applicable answer for this question when seraching Google, Stackoverflow or any other source, so I decided to ask my own here.

In GNU Bash (Ubuntu), I'm trying to ONLY replace special characters that are between quotes in a file called test.txt, which has the following contents

```
foo_bar "foo_bar"
```

so that the resulting contents would be

```
foo_bar "foo bar"
```

Currently I haven't had any luck, I've tried several solutions such as

```
touch test2.txt
grep -o '".*"' test.txt | sed s/"_"/" "/g > test2.txt
rm test.txt
rename s/"test2"/"test"/ test2.txt
```

which would otherwise be fine, but that command causes the file content to only be "foo bar", not the whole file. I'm looking for a way to directly replace quoted special characters inside files, both sed and awk will do.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/_/, " ", $i)} 1' file
foo_bar "foo bar"
```

Comment: What will happen if the following occurs: `foo bar "bar\"baz"`?

Comment: Not sure if escaped quotes are OP's requirements. If yes then answer needs to be modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I was able to put them to good use.

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
sed -ri 's/("[^_]*)_([^_]*")/\1 \2/g' test
```

- `-r` enables extended regular expressions so you don't have to escape `()`
- `-i` replaces input file with result in-place
- `("[^_]*)` matches `"` followed by anything *but* `_` (repeated zero or more times) and captures the match
- `([^_]*")` matches anything *but* `_` (repeated zero or more times) followed by `"` and captures the match
- `\1` and `\2` are backreferences to the captured groups
- `g` is the "global" modifier: the substitution is repeated as often as possible on the same line

This only works with well-formed expressions (even number of quotes) and doesn't deal with escaped quotes.